# How to build a form listing user roles in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I want to display a form having checkboxes against every user role
I have this

```
$roles = user_roles($membersonly = FALSE, $permission = NULL);

$form['trc_user_roles'] = array(
        '#type'         =>  'chekboxes',
        '#title'        =>  'Allow users who can see uploaded files',
        '#options'      =>  $roles,
        '#descripion'   =>  'User roles checked are able to see site-wide uploads.'
    );

return system_settings_form($form);
```

The output is a blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your call to `user_roles()` and a spelling error ('chekboxes'). Try this:

```
$roles = user_roles(FALSE, NULL);

$form['trc_user_roles'] = array(
  '#type'         =>  'checkboxes',
  '#title'        =>  'Allow users who can see uploaded files',
  '#options'      =>  $roles,
  '#descripion'   =>  'User roles checked are able to see site-wide uploads.',
  '#default_value' => variable_get('trc_user_roles', array())
);

return system_settings_form($form);
```

I've also added a `#default_value` attribute so the next time you re-load the form the selected options will be pre-filled in.